# OneNote is laggy and takes too long to respond

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I have a ThinkPad Yoga and I use it for taking notes in class. The problem is, OneNote is not as good as expected. I'm using Office 365 University (so I'm not on the metro app).

I'm also always in the Auto-Papersize-Mode. The problems are:

-When scrolling with via touch, it lags badly.
-When not touching it and not writing on it, it might take a few seconds to recognize the pen, so I always have to wait a few seconds before I can start writing again.
-When pressing the Button for enabling the rubber, it sometimes takes more than 10 seconds until it actually works.
-I'd like to have the rubber while pressing the button - currently by pressing the button, I switch to the rubber and then I have to go away from the screen, so that OneNote resets the pen to aehm "pen mode".

I'm always in Energy saving mode. What can I do to improve performance? I want it to be smooth without lag. The Hardware is fine, I'm sure. (i5, SSD, 8GB Ram)

Answer (score 2):

Ah yes, Office 365/2013. There are a couple of things that can cause this. Starting with most likely:

**1. New animations silliness in Office**

Doesn't work well with some devices, so disable it:

http://withinwindows.com/2012/07/21/disabling-animations-in-office-2013

**2. Unnecessary system-wide animations**

Again, doesn't work well with some devices, so disable it:

1. Open Ease of Access Center (keyboard shortcut is Windows Logo Key + U)
2. Under *Explore all settings*, click *Use the computer without a display*
3. Under *Adjust time limits and flashing visuals*, click *Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible)*.
4. Click OK.

As a side-note, how wacked is it that an animation-related setting is found under an option called *Use the computer **without** a display*? Another wonderful Windows-ism.

**3. Something else?**

Unfortunately the problem could be something else entirely:

- Video driver is not up-to-date. Download and install latest video driver for your Yoga by using Microsoft Update or directly from Lenovo support website.
- Other device drivers are not up-to-date. Solution same as above.
- You're storing notebook files on OneDrive and a slow internet connection is causing lags. Try create a new notebook and select the option *My Computer* when it asks. Close all other notebooks except the new one and test.

Good luck, do let us know how you go :-)

Comment: Couldn't try everything yet but changing the mode from energy saving mode to balanced etc. makes quite an effect. I also deleted all teh cache which was good. Thanks